# Gifting of money by USA residing son to his parents

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india, gift-tax

My son wants to remit some money in his mother's account jointly with me(father). It is very much clear that it will be tax free in India being a gift.

Does Income Tax department need some proof to treat this amount as gift? Is there any mandatory set of documents or deed that are required? OR We simply asked our son to send some thing on plain paper / scanned copy signed by him to declare that this amount is given as gift which is gifted to us through this cheque number/date/bank etc?

Does our son need to show this amount as gift in his yearly return or not. What are the implications to his tax return due to gifted money in the US?

Comment: Please turn off your CAPS lock.

Comment: Hey Bobby - I had bookmarked [this site](https://convertcase.net/) to help with a quick edit. Just took care of the body of the question.

Comment: How much is he giving you? Is your son married?

Answer (score 1):

> Should we have to prepare any documents or deed or we simply asked our son to send on line a scanned copy on simple paper signed by him to declare that this amt is given as gift which is gifted to us through this cheque number/date/bank etc?

Depending on amount, if few thousands don't bother. If few lacs get it on a simple plain paper, if in crores, get a proper gift deed executed.

There is no tax for you.

> My son wants to remit some money in his mother's account jointly with me(father). It is very much clear that it will be tax free in india being a gift but how will this amt be treated as gift in the eyes of income tax people? Should we have to prepare any documents or deed or we simply asked our son to send on line a scanned copy on simple paper signed by him to declare that this amt is given as gift which is gifted to us through this cheque number/date/bank etc?

Whether our son shows that amt as gift in his yearly return or not. what are the implications to his tax return due to gifted

As your son is US citizen, he can only gift USD 14,000 to you and equal amount to your mother in a year. Similarly your daughter in law can give you both 14000 each. If it is more, he has to pay taxes or claim it against life time exemption of 1 million (?) USD

Comment: My son is not US citizen and he is unmarried. He want to gift  INR 5 To 6 lacs in a  year which is appx $7400 to 9000 to his mother.

Comment: @SatyendraKumarGupta If you son's tax status is "Resident Alien" in US, the rules are same as US Resident. Less than $14000 shouldn't be an issue.